# Flutter Send Notification Given Date and Time

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications

I'm trying to send a notification to a user given the date and time entered. For this I'm using flutter local notifications. However, the notification only pops up when I press the Run main.dart button at the exact date and time. How can I fix this to where the notification pops up without having to press the run button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this package for Scheduling a notification - [flutter_local_notifications: ^9.0.2](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)

**Note** In the iOS platform you can schedule a maximum 64 notifications. if it is more than 64 then it will overlap (the older ones will be dropped and not delivered).